# xbindkeys double counting keypresses (not distinguishing between press and release)

Tags: xbindkeys

I have a Logitech g502 Proteus mouse, and want to use the "Back" and "Forward" mouse buttons (typically used with browser).

I verified with `xev` that the mouse button presses are detected.  I installed `xbindkeys` and using various online references setup `.xbindkeysrc` to map the mouse buttons (6 and 7) to press a series of keys to emulate the correct behavior.

```
"xte 'key t'"
     b:6 + Release

"xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'keydown Right' 'keyup Right' 'keyup Alt_L'"
     b:7 + Release
```

The problem, the remap is executed twice, once on press, and once on release.  I thought the "Release" modifier would solve this, but it's still ongoing.  I verified this by putting in a dummy remap to the letter `'t'`, holding down the mouse button, and seeing one `'t'` inserted, followed by another `'t'` on release when I let go.

I did kill all the xbindkeys processes before testing also.   running `xbindkeys --verbose --nodaemon` shows an unusual behavior, in that a `press` and `release` are both recorded when I press a mouse button, despite my not releasing the depressed mouse button. The following looks like I pressed and released the button twice, but it was only once:

```
starting loop...
Button press !
e.xbutton.button=6
e.xbutton.state=16
Button release !
e.xbutton.button=6
e.xbutton.state=16
"xte 'key t' "
    Release + m:0x0 + b:6   (mouse)
got screen 0 for window 510
Start program with fork+exec call

Button press !
e.xbutton.button=6
e.xbutton.state=16
Button release !
e.xbutton.button=6
e.xbutton.state=16
"xte 'key t' "
    Release + m:0x0 + b:6   (mouse)
got screen 0 for window 510
```

The xte lines themselves on the command line print only one 't.'   Any ideas on how to fix/workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

I use `xbindkeys` in a similar way on one PC to to workspace switching with the mouse side buttons. Looking at my config I see I have `&amp;` at the end of my `xte` config lines which I believe runs `xte` in the background. Perhaps you need that? I am not at that PC to check what happens if I remove tha `&amp;` from my config:

```
        # Mouse button 8 (the "back" side button)
        # Re-map to super+page-down (move to workspace down)
        "xte 'keydown Super_L' 'key Page_Down' 'keyup Super_L' &amp;"
          b:8

        # Mouse button 9 (the "forward" side button)
        # Re-map to super+page-up (move to workspace up)
        "xte 'keydown Super_L' 'key Page_Up' 'keyup Super_L' &amp;"
          b:9
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried that and it gave an error `sh: 1: amp: not found` so still searching for some explanation.  I am doing this in a Hyper-V VM, but no other keys, mouse or otherwise, have this behavior.  I tried replacing `b:6` (backwards mouse button) with `b:1` (mouse left click) and it works as intended.  Holding left click down, I only get a "Button press" state, until I release it.

Comment: EDIT: Scrutinzing the `xev` output shows  button 6 & 7 register as  press AND release even when just pressed.  So perhaps` xkeybind` is behaving as expected, but why does the mouse have this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like this not an issue with Ubuntu or xbindkeys, but with the xrdp mouse driver.  I am using an MS Hyper-V VM running Ubuntu 20.04.2, and I came across the following issue on github where someone reports my problem exactly, a "single click (press+release) of a Logitech MX Vertical mouse of button 6 and 7 (forward/backward buttons) two ButtonPress and ButtonRelease events are sent."

[xrdpmouse: ButtonPress/ButtonRelease event sent twice](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xorgxrdp/issues/162)

So it seems like there's no easy fix, which is unfortunate.